# How to repaint UIView when text in UILabel changes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I've a subclass of *UIView* with a *UILabel* with is added as subview to the view. In the *layoutSubviews* method the position and height of the *UILabel* is calculated. My problem is, that this height should be recalculated, when the text of the UILabel changes. The text is inserted into the label from the UIViewController, so the view does not know when this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `UILabel` to override `setText:` like this:

```
@implementation MyLabel

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    [super setText:text];
    [self.superview setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: The does not seems as a very flexible solution. In fact it is not just a UILabel I need to repaint - i.e. also the size of a UIImageView when its image is replaced.

Comment: Neither `UILabel` nor `UIImageView` has an option to automatically resize itself when its content changes.  You have to tell it to resize.  You can either do it from the code which changes the content (which might be lots of places), or you can make subclasses.